# Showing blocks with label/inputs elements are on different row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In jquery 3.4.1 app I have several blocks with label/inputs which are
hidden/shown when checkbox with method backendClient.cbxHasPartialPaymentsOnChange is clicked.
I want to show label/inputs on 1 row:

```
                <div class="form-row mb-5 mt-3">
                    <label for="cbx_has_partial_payments" class="col-6 col-form-label">Has partial payments</label>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 pt-2">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cbx_has_partial_payments" id="cbx_has_partial_payments"
                               name="cbx_has_partial_payments" value="1"
                               onchange="javascript:backendClient.cbxHasPartialPaymentsOnChange();">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-row" id="div_invoice_rent">
                    <label for="invoice_rent_formatted" class="col-6 col-form-label">12345 Invoice rent 99</label>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 pt-2">
                        {!! $viewFuncs->text('invoice_rent_formatted', '', "form-control editable_field",
                            ["maxlength"=>"255","autocomplete"=>"off", "readonly"=> "readonly" ] ) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>


...
backendClient.prototype.cbxHasPartialPaymentsOnChange = function () {
    var has_partial_payments = $("#cbx_has_partial_payments").prop("checked");
    $("#div_invoice_rent").css("display", ( has_partial_payments && parseFloat(this_openedInvoice.rent) > 0 ) ? "block" : "none" );

...
```

Method backendClient.cbxHasPartialPaymentsOnChange is  also clicked when the form opened and block
id="div_invoice_rent" is hidden and clicks on checkbox (setting it to true) labels and inputs are on
different row and that is not what I expect.

if to comment row :

```
backendClient.prototype.cbxHasPartialPaymentsOnChange = function () {
    var has_partial_payments = $("#cbx_has_partial_payments").prop("checked");
//    $("#div_invoice_rent").css("display", ( has_partial_payments && parseFloat(this_openedInvoice.rent) > 0 ) ? "block" : "none" );
```

then label/inputs are on 1 row.
What is wrong in my condition and how to fix it?

Thanks!